# How to blink notification icon in android? [DONE]

Tags: android, notifications, blink

I searched many things as like :
    [How to show icon blinking on google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729255/how-to-show-icon-blinking-on-google-map)

but according to this i don't find how to blink notification icon blink

i want to blink icon on this

```
 int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Hi M rohit", when);
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "Rohit", intent);
//notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found solution :i created animation file and set that file , thanks i found solution

SET FILE name here:-

```
   int icon = R.drawable.animationfile;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Your location is tracing", when);
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Home.class);
// set intent so it does not start a new activity
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, "Rohit", intent);
//notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION, notification);
```

i created this file

animationfile.xml :

```
  <animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icaon" android:duration="10000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icon" android:duration="10000" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: It didn't work without having a ticker set! It was shown but wasn't animated. It looks like it will only be animated if you also call setTicker(...).

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem I guess it's linked to that bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15657

Answer (score 3):

To show the upload or download notification like the default one which we have in android (an up or down arrow moving up or down respectively like this [image: like], till the upload or download is completed), simply use the below.

Set your notification builder to,

```
mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download);
mBuilder.setTicker(mContext.getString(R.string.notification_ticker)); //Pass an empty string if you dont want any text to appear on the status bar
//Call notify() method of notification manager to see the effect
```

And when you want the animated icon to stop after the upload or download is completed use below,

```
 mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_download); //ic_download is similar looking icon in your drawable folder
 mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Hope this helps. :)