# How to set animation on Notification Badge in Xamarin Android

Tags: animation, xamarin.android

I want to set animation on Notification Badge and how to display the badge infront of the imageview(Z axis)

Answer (score 0):

According to the following thread, we can see that Android does not allow changing of the application.

[How to display count of notifications in app launcher icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565307/how-to-display-count-of-notifications-in-app-launcher-icon)

But If you still want to animation for notification, I suggest you can implement animation for Android Notification bar.

It needs one animationfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animation-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/icaon" android:duration="10000" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_button_click" android:duration="10000" />
 </animation-list>


  int icon = Resource.Drawable.animationfile;

        // Build the notification:
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                      .SetAutoCancel(true) // Dismiss the notification from the notification area when the user clicks on it
                      .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent) // Start up this activity when the user clicks the intent.
                      .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked") // Set the title
                      .SetNumber(count) // Display the count in the Content Info
                                        //.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_stat_button_click) // This is the icon to display
                      .SetSmallIcon(icon)
                      .SetContentText($"The button has been clicked {count} times."); // the message to display.

        // Finally, publish the notification:
        var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
        notificationManager.Notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.Build());
```

Here is the same thread, you can take a look:

[How to blink notification icon in android? [DONE]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266289/how-to-blink-notification-icon-in-android-done)